# Is it possible to de-obfuscate java project completely?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to decompile .apk to get source code.I followed some tutorials and finally i got project from .apk. But all package is located com folder and src folder is empty.When i tried to move them to src folder, i got error in every single class because of project is obfuscated.Is is possible to de-obfuscate all these classes.Following code make it clear.All these a,b,ab,c etc. are obfuscated classes and methods.Is it possible to de-obfuscate them?

```
public void a(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3, int paramInt4)
  {
    if ((this.H) && (paramInt4 >= 482 - this.ab.c) && (paramInt4 <= 482))
      a(7, null, 5);
  }

  public void a(int paramInt, m paramm)
  {
    switch (paramInt)
    {
    default:
      return;
    case 6:
      e();
      a(false, 0, 0.5F);
      c(6, 0);
      return;
    case 5:
      e();
      this.K.F = false;
      this.P.F = false;
      this.R.F = false;
      this.H = false;
      a(false, 0, 0.5F);
      this.ac = 0;
      this.J.a();
      this.ao = 2;
      this.ak = 1;
      this.y = 0;
      this.al.a();
      this.A = (1 + this.A);
      c(7, 0);
      return;
    case 2:
      this.I = true;
      c(0, this.y);
      this.am.a();
      c(8, 0);
      return;
    case 3:
      c(11, 0);
      return;
    case 4:
      c(13, 0);
      return;
    case 7:
    }
    c(3, 0);
  }
```

Comment: If you knew what the original name of each class and each method was, you could use the refactor/rename feature of an IDE like Eclipse.  If you don't know any of the original names, then there's not much you can do.

Comment: Automatically? No. But you can reinvent meaningful names manually.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is possibly about violating software licensing terms and conditions, and is not about programming.  Ask the developers for the code or, if it's open source, download it.  Otherwise, you have no right to do this.

Comment: By hand? yes. Analyse the logic and try to make sense of all the a's and b's. Can we do it automated? Not really.. You'd might wanna try Java Deobfuscator (JDO). It just makes the everything a little bit more readable.

Comment: No it isn't possible, and a good job too. It's been obfuscated to stop people violating copyright.

Comment: There are reasons to do that without intention to violate copyright. One example would be if you are forced to use a 3rd party library with lousy documentation and need to know what a certain function is doing exactly.

Comment: @Henrry.  I've never seen a software license agreement that says, "no reverse engineering unless <insert good intention here>".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the rough Overview of how the code structure is by using dex2jar,JDecompiler or whatever decompiler tool you're using.

But ,dude you won't get the exact code from it.**It's meant for obfuscation.**

**And if writing and stealing code would be so easy, then why developer get paid for?**

Instead of seeing other's source code ,try starting to write your own.

By the way I agree with Simon's comment

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is possibly about violating software licensing terms and conditions, and is not about programming. Ask the developers for the code or, if it's open source, download it. Otherwise, you have no right to do this